# How to extract the same entries from two tables?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have 30000 entries in two tables. Now, I want to extract those two entries which are the same. How can I do it? For example, I have two tables, say T1 and T2;

```
T1={{1.3,2.6},{2,3.6},{4,6.9},{2,9.3},{3,1.1},{5,1.2}};
T2={{2,2.6},{1.3,2.6},{4,6.7},{2,9.3},{3,1.8},{5,1.7},{5,1.2},{3,1.1}};
```

Here, `{1.3,2.6},{2,9.3},{3,1.1}` and `{5,1.2}` are same for both tables. How could we extract them?

Comment: Try `Intersection[T1, T2]`?

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: @creidhne Might be good to add that as an answer so we can close this one.